# Get data through Hibernate without Entity classes

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

We use Hibernate and annotations to map our db and entities. But for some data tables I don't want entity classes (Because these table names and all are keep changing) so that the application will be more dynamic

1. So is it possible using hibernate to load data from a table without a entity class?
2. If so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate provides a way to execute SQL query and to map it to an entity or any class : [native sql queries](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/query-native/Native.html).

Comment: But the tables are not mapped! Hibernate doesn't know about the ones that are not annotated. The question says "a table without a entity class".

Comment: And so ? I don't think that you need to configure them with Hibernate to make them query-able. While I never tested it. I think that native sql queries are just a way to write and execute JDBC queries.

Comment: Thanks I'll use this way

Answer (score 1):

Use plain JDBC. I'm not sure what you mean by "table names and all are keep changing" but it sounds like a bad idea to me.

What you could do is create the sql query using string concatenation then use plain JDBC to execute it. That way you can keep table names dynamic.

Comment: table names are kept on a different data table. for different situation we have to use different tables. so rather than creating entity classes for each table is there a way to get those data?

Comment: It sounds like you would be better off using a database without a fixed schema. Take a look at some NoSQL databases like MongoDB,

Comment: Thanks, But the problem is we are so far into the project right now and we can't move to a new DB system.

Answer (score 1):

> - If *Persistence class* won't be used, then the data encapsulation won't    occur thus data can be accessed directly.
> - *Hibernate Queries* interact with the *POJO class* to fetch data.
> - Query, Criteria, HQL all the classes use the *POJO* for fetching data.
> - Hibernate Framework was mainly designed for the *ORM Mapping*.
> - Thus without *POJO class*, not possible to interact with the database.

Thus using *JDBC connection* would be the option left.

Answer (score 1):

Use Dynamic models introduced in Hibernate 5 version - 5.4.0.Final
[Hibernate Dynamic Models](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/persistent-classes-dynamicmodels.html)
To achieve this you will need HBM files created.

```
Session s = openSession();
Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
Session s = openSession();

// Create a customer
Map david = new HashMap();
david.put("name", "David");

// Create an organization
Map foobar = new HashMap();
foobar.put("name", "Foobar Inc.");

// Link both
david.put("organization", foobar);

// Save both
s.save("Customer", david);
s.save("Organization", foobar);

tx.commit();
s.close();
```

Here Customer & Organization are table names
Organization is Parent of Customer.
Click on the above link for more details